# How to update Android Studio from a zip file?

Tags: updates, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.1, and I downloaded latest update. It was given as a zip folder. How to update Android studio from that folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** Android Studio, even when zipped, is a huge file to download without being interrupted. If you have a poor internet connection, I would recommend using a download manager. It obviously cannot reduce the file size, but even if the download is interrupted, it can continue without hiccups while ensuring file integrity.

**Steps to install Android Studio from a .zip folder:**

- If you have Windows:

  1. Open the .zip folder using Windows Explorer.
  2. Click on 'Extract all' (or 'Extract all files') option in the ribbon.
  3. Enter any extract location you like. Extract them.
  4. Go to the extract location.
     Go to `android-studio\bin` and run `studio.exe`.
  5. Go through the installation wizard. You are done.
- If you have any other OS:

  1. Figure out how to unpack zip files on your platform.
  2. Unpack the zip file
  3. Go to the extract location, to `android-studio/bin` and run the studio executable for your OS.
  4. Go through the installation wizard. You are done.

If using Ubuntu (or Linux in general), copy over the `android-studio` folder to `/opt` for a system-wide installation.

Comment: These steps worked fine for me. I updated Android studio 1.2 to 1.4 using Windows.

Comment: Worked fine for me updating from 1.3 to 1.51. 
I had to rename the old "Android Studio" folder and then extract the zip to Android Studio (Taking the name of the original folder)

Comment: "Enter the extract location". Which location? Any location or where Android Studio is currently installed? Also, On Step 4, I open AS and it gives me a dialog about "Keep old settings" or something similar; I accidentally closed AS at this point, and no matter what I do I can't get that dialog to open again.

Comment: Dear @NewWorld , Save anywhere you can(No offence, but I guess that is obvious. Installers don't scan computers for previous installations(they may) & thus "Keep old settings". For your problem, I suggest deleting the extracted folder and re-extracting.

Comment: @VaradMahashabde When you say "*the*" extract location; it sounds like you're talking about a specific location; "an extract location" would be clearer. I did try to delete and re-extract the folder, but it didn't work. To solve the problem I had to download the AS installer and install that, rather than use the .zip file.

Comment: I added the changes

Comment: @SpaghettiCat You have to first delete the current android studio folder in C -> Program Files -> Android in order to remove the old version. Then extract the zip file to this location before installing the application from the bin folder as above. Select I don't have a version of android studio on my P.C. and it will automatically detect the sdk that was installed with the previous version. Select it and everything else should work on default install settings.

Comment: Also, you should remember to say that "run studio64.exe if you are running a 64-bit system"

Answer (score 0):

> If you want early access to the next version of Android Studio, you don't have to replace your existing stable version. You can install the Android Studio preview side by side with the stable version and work on the same app projects in both.

[Install a preview version of Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview)